# ADAL cordova: how to skip the discover page in Azure AD

Tags: cordova-plugins, adal

I am trying to create ionic app using adal cordova. Everytime, acquiretokenasync is called, the login dialog pop up with the first time where AAD is trying to determine what you domain you are using and then redirect next to actual login page. I found on the web http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/11/17/skipping-the-home-realm-discovery-page-in-azure-ad/

but not sure how it works in cordova. Anyone has any idea? I appreciate your time and efforts to read and answer my question.